# Complex Sql Query for my project

Tags: sql

pls help me to execute this query. I already did everything but turns that my queries not working. Please help.

Table

```
ITEM
     id     Name      
     1      Computer 1
     2      Computer 2


STATUS
    id    Stat_Name
    1     Stock In
    2     Stock Out

INVENTORY
    id    Item_id    Status_id  Quantity
    1     1          1          100
    2     1          2          200
    3     1          1          30
   4     2          1          35
   5     2          2          36
```

I want this output
Output:

```
Item        overall_stock_in    overall_stock_out
    Computer1   130                 200
    Computer2   35                  36
```

Thanks Guys

Comment: please format your data like code (use 4 spaces indentation ) so that this becomes readable.

Comment: ok just wait i will send the image of my table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  B.Id,
  B.Name, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN A.Status_id=1 THEN A.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS overall_stock_in,
  SUM(CASE WHEN A.Status_id=2 THEN A.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS overall_stock_out
FROM INVENTORY A JOIN ITEM B ON A.Item_id=B.id
GROUP BY B.Id, B.Name
ORDER BY B.Name;
```

See [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/311be/1).

Answer (score 0):

Using status table as well
(Updated @cdaiga's query):

```
SELECT 
C.Name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN B.Status_Name='Stock In' THEN A.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 
overall_stock_in,
SUM(CASE WHEN B.Status_Name='Stock Out' THEN A.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 
overall_stock_out
FROM INVENTORY A JOIN ITEM C ON A.Item_id=C.id
JOIN "status" B ON A.Status_id=B.id
GROUP BY C.Name
ORDER BY C.Name;
```

Comment: There is no need to add a join and increase complexity when you already know the status ids. You see that in any way you will still need a window function with the case. So to me an extra join is redundant.